# ReferenceError: initializeFieldsetDataByDefault is not defined Upgrade issue Magento 2.2.2

Tags: upgrade, magento2.2.2

I have upgraded website from 2.0.7 to Magento 2.2.2 but when i try to open product or category in admin than console showing me below error.

```
ReferenceError: initializeFieldsetDataByDefault is not defined
```

Also exception log is showing below error

```
main.CRITICAL: The element 'gallery' already has a child with alias 'content' {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): The element 'gallery' already has a child with alias 'content' at /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Data/Structure.php:611)"} []
```

You can see the screenshot below for admin layout.

https://prnt.sc/iby5fv

Let me know if any one has a solution.

Looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Having the same issue? Was that resolved?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/158901)